# gcnew operator for generic type

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have the following simple class

```
generic<typename T> where T:IDbConnection ref class CDbConnection
{
private:    
    IDbConnection^m_db;

    ConnectionState^ m_originalConnState;
public:
    CDbConnection();
    bool Connect(String ^ connStr);
    bool Exists(int id);
    auto GetAllData(String^ tableStr);
    ~CDbConnection();   
    !CDbConnection();
};
```

and here is my constructor

```
generic<typename T> CDbConnection<T>::CDbConnection()
{
    m_db=gcnew T();
    m_originalConnState=m_db->State;
}
```

But the compiler complains <1> the gcnew T() can't be used for generic type
<2> `auto` key in use is wrong as the function `expects a trailing return type`

Comment: Why do you declare your member `m_db` as `IDbConnection` and yet treat it as a generic using `m_db = gcnew T()`?

Comment: Thanks, I would like to later do something like this `"m_db=gcnew SqlConnection()/OracleConnection()/DbOleConnection();"` etc

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your reading and replies

I forgot this 
`where T:IDbConnection, gcnew()`
which is exactly the same as C# generics

to get rid of the `gcnew` error as stated above.

Comment: Fall in the pit of success by writing code inline.  C++/CLI often doesn't require separating the declaration from the definition of a class, header files are replaced by assembly metadata.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve genericity, you must change your class definition to

```
generic<typename T> where T:IDbConnection ref class CDbConnection
{
private:    

    T m_db;
    ConnectionState^ m_originalConnState;

public:

    CDbConnection();
    bool Connect(String ^ connStr);
    bool Exists(int id);
    auto GetAllData(String^ tableStr);
    ~CDbConnection();   
    !CDbConnection();
};
```

As you are already constraining your `T` to be at least `IDbConnection` it can't be anything else.
Then your constructor

```
generic<typename T> CDbConnection<T>::CDbConnection()
{
    m_originalConnState=m_db.State;
}
```

should work like you intended.

EDIT

It seems you cannot declare a reference to a generic. If you assign the object to the stack it will work.
See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf16h0a6.aspx) entry.

```
// C3229.cpp
// compile with: /clr /c
generic <class T>
ref class C {
   T^ t;   // C3229
};

// OK
generic <class T>
ref class D {
   T u;
};
```

Comment: Thank you but it results in a new error that states `"indirections on a generic type parameter are not allowed"`